# "Kekkosema wa"?

Tags: meaning, listening

First post on JLSE. Sorry if this doesn't belong here...

Sometimes on the train platforms in Tokyo or on Japanese television, I hear a phrase that sounds like "kekk-sema-wa." I'm still early in my Japanese studies and am having a hard time breaking it down to figure out what it means. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you're hearing (お)[客様]{きゃくさま}は [(o)kyaku-sama wa]. 客 means "customer" and お and 様 you might already know as being honorifics.